# Is 2005 bottle wheat beer ok to drink?

Tags: storage

Found a box of home brewed beer in an old cellar marked 2005. Bottles look ok and caps are good. Would it be safe to drink?

Comment: Please drink one and post back here with a comment telling us how it tastes! While it won't hurt you, I suspect it might taste stale, or like wet cardboard from oxidation. Or, it might be delicious!

Comment: Get it cold, then taste it. Take a giant gulp, don't be afraid! But dont forget to put your video cam on a tripod sop we can see your face on youtube, good or bad! :)

Answer (score 6):

It will be safe to drink - beer doesn't go bad in a way that can cause illness. If it will taste good or not is another thing altogether!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why it wont be ok to drink. There is nothing wrong with opening one and trying a little bit to see how it tastes.

If it tastes all good then put the rest in the fridge and enjoy.

Comment: Higher gravity and bottle conditioning will go a long way toward preserving cellar stored beers. Hops may subside a bit but otherwise, should be good unless stored at higher temps.

Answer (score 1):

Try one and pour it in a glass gently to see if there is year sediment.  If there is some, that means that the beer was bottle conditioned (good sign) but still try to keep the sediment out of the glass as much as possible.

There are some wheat beers that get better with age if this is a Belgian or select German style!